# NSData in base 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

Is it possible to NSLog NSData in base 10. Basically to see byte array of NSData.

I would like to see output something like this: [51, -55, 55, -54, -110]

Comment: And what have you tried? It is really trivial if you have read the documentation for `NSLog()`.

Comment: In general, hexadecimal output is more appropiate for binary data.

Comment: @duDE it is not duplicate. My question was not how to print NSData.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a *category* on `NSData` to produce a string with decimal data representation, like this:

```
@interface NSData (DecimalOutput)
-(NSString*)asDecimalString;
@end
@implementation NSData (DecimalOutput)
-(NSString*)asDecimalString {
    NSMutableString *res = [NSMutableString string];
    [res appendString:@"["];
    // Construct an `NSString`, for example by appending decimal representations
    // of individual bytes to the output string
    const char *p = [self bytes];
    NSUInteger len = [self length];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0 ; i != len ; i++) {
        [res appendFormat:@"%i ", p[i]];
    }
    [res appendString:@"]"];
    return res;
}
@end
```

Now you can use this to `NSLog` strings in the new format:

```
NSLog("Data:%@", [myData asDecimalString]);
```

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't think it's the "create a category" idea that OP is missing - it's rather the `appendFormat:@"%d ", ((const char *)data.bytes)[i]]` part.

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm not that fast at typing :)

Comment: Ah OK :) Cheating, huh? :P (still `const char *`, btw.)

Comment: @H2CO3 Ninja edits are perfectly fine - they are one of the more exciting parts of being on Stack Overflow :)